# UK Standard Visitor Visa: how long does it take to get application acknowledgement?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My wife and I applied for a UK Standard visitor visa at the New York consulate. We sent in the documents and they have reached the mail room yesterday according to UPS.

Does anyone know how long it takes to get an email stating that they have received everything and are processing the applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emails are sent from the Proviso System, triggered by events during the process. The first such event is application receipt and, if it arrived yesterday, likely it would be opened today (Friday) or the next business day (Monday, in this case). Should you not receive a confirmation, don't panic. It can be nothing more than a heavier than usual workload, or a glitch at Proviso. The system indicates processing, not decisions. So, if all goes according to plan, you might expect to hear something Monday or Tuesday.